# Create own certificates structure in C

Tags: c, openssl, certificate, x509

Imagine that I want be a certificate authority that issues its own certificates. I would like to be able to generate my own certificates with the fields I want. Is this possible to be done in anyway? Using OpenSSL or any other libraries? I would like to be able to create a very compact certificate which would have no more that a the public key, signature and a Identification. Something that would be about 250-bytes maximum, which is quite less compared with the certificates generated using openSSL, about 950 bytes.

The field that I would like my certificate to have would be:

The algorithm used should be ECDSA 224 ou 256, with SHA 256, expiry time, generation time, allow revocation of certificates and carry an Identification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do anything you want, BUT, if you're concerned at all about security, or if you are interested in being compatible with applications other than your own, you shouldn't do this.

In general, "rolling your own" security solution is a BAD idea.  There are standards for a reason.  They have been peer reviewed, tested, and are transparent.

But just for curiosity, let's walk through what would be required for your question.

First, you need a public key.  Currently, the secure recommendation is about 2048 bits or 256 bytes.  With just the key, we are already over your maximum of 250 bytes.

Next, you need a signature.  A standard signature will be equal to the key size: 2048 bits (256 bytes).

Then you need identification.  You didn't say what the identification was.  Let's say it's the string, "Identity 1".  This takes up about 10 bytes.  It is also very limiting and doesn't scale very well.

You didn't mention if you wanted an issuer identity, but let's throw that in for another 10 bytes.

And what about a serial #?  Do you want any way of revoking these certificates if they become compromised?  Do you want to identify the signature algorithm, or will it always be the same?  Do you want expiration dates on the certificate?  What about usage?  Do you want to differentiate which roles the certs can have?  All of these add to the byte count.

Let's say you don't want anything in the previous paragraph.  Without that, we're already at 532 bytes total.

And what about formatting?  We probably can't just stick all these bytes together.  There needs to be some kind of structured formatting for the certificate values (similar to ASN.1 encoding used in X509).  That will add additional bytes to the total.

So you can see why a certificate generated by OpenSSL can easily be over 650 bytes.

The bottom line is that it depends on what you intend to use this for.  Are you just playing around in your own sandbox and not interested in compatibility or security?  Then go ahead and make your own certificate format.  But otherwise, stick to the standards.

Comment: Hi. First of all thanks. I am trying to implement a standard for security in vehicular communications. The standard defines that a compact certificate must be created for performance reasons. The algorithm used should be ECDSA 224 ou 256, with SHA 256, expiry time, generation time, allow revocation of certificates, Identification. I think it is all as far I remember.

Comment: If you're using ECDSA, the public key size needed will be significantly smaller.  However, I would still strongly caution about generating your own certificate standard and PKI.  It's easy to miss something, and if you miss something, the consequences can be HUGE.  For example, Sony implemented an ECDSA solution incorrectly.  Here is the [story](http://www.exophase.com/20540/hackers-describe-ps3-security-as-epic-fail-gain-unrestricted-access/).

Comment: Ok, I understand that, but this would be for academic purpose to understand how things work. Is there any framework or anything that allows me the creation of my own certificates will only the field I want? Thanks Best Regards

Comment: As I have referred this is for academic purposes, so I have to create a certificate only with some data field I want. Do I have to create it programatically by myself or is there any framework, that given the algorithm, in this case the ECDSA it generates my private key, public key and certificate with only the field I define int the system. What I would like to know is if there is a software to create own defined certificate structures.

Comment: I don't know of any specific framework that does what you're asking.  You can use OpenSSL to create keys and sign information, so theoretically, you can create your own "structure" with a public key and then sign it, including the signature as part of the "certificate".